# How is dpos_proposed_irreversible_blocknum aka PLIB computed?

Tags: eosio-code, voting

How is [dpos_proposed_irreversible_blocknum](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/block_header_state.cpp#L204) aka [Pre-LIB (Last Irreversible Block)](https://medium.com/eosio/dpos-bft-pipelined-byzantine-fault-tolerance-8a0634a270ba) computed? Is it by counting 15 blocks or by counting 15 signatures?

For example: In an unfortunate scenario, out of 4 Block Producers (BP) couple of honest BPs miss their designated time slot: A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 A3.
I am not sure if A2 gets three (A2+B2+A3) votes or two votes (only A and B have voted).

Answer (score 0):

It is by signature, you have the exact full processus in the controller.cpp files: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/libraries/chain/controller.cpp#L810-L864

In your example, the block will be validated once 15 unique BP validate it, no matter if it is one that were not designated to produce during the block creation